# Writing complex mysql Queries

Tags: mysql

The database needs to keep track of information about registered users of the website and the videos that they upload, view, and rate. Each uploaded video is put into one of a predefined set of content categories. A user can watch the same video multiple times; they may give a different rating to a video each time they view it, or they may not rate it at all.

To make money, the video sharing service depends on revenue generated from advertising. When a user views a video, they are often (but not always) shown an advertisement before the video begins. Any user can create an advertisement and pay a fixed total price to have it shown a specified number of times (number of views wanted). The advertiser can target their advertising at users with relevant interests by specifying one or more content categories for their advertisement; advertisements are more likely to be shown together with videos in those selected categories. For accounting and statistical purposes, the database tracks when advertisements are shown and whether or not users clicked on the advertisement.

Some prolific users who have uploaded many high quality videos may be invited into a revenue-sharing partnership in which they get paid a fraction of the earnings from advertisements that are shown on their uploaded videos.

I have the following database created in MySql:

USERS
(username,password,name,email,date_registered)

ViDEOS
(video_id,title,uploaded_by,uploaded_at,category)

ADVERTISEMENTS
(ad_id,advertiser,price,views_wanted)

Ad_Target_Categories
(ad_id,category)

VIEWS
(user,video,viewed_at,rating,ad_shown,ad_clicked)

PARTNERS
(username,revenue_share)

I have created the database using the SQL statements :

```
create table Users
(
username varchar(400) not null,
password varchar(400) not null,
name varchar(400) not null,
email varchar(400) not null,
date_registered date,
primary key(username)
);

create table Videos
(
video_id varchar(400) not null,
title varchar(400) not null,
uploaded_by varchar(400) not null,
uploaded_at varchar(400) not null,
category varchar(400) not null,
primary key(video_id),
foreign key(uploaded_by) references Users(username)
);

create table Advertisements
(
ad_id varchar(400) not null,
advertiser varchar(400) not null,
price varchar(400) not null,
views_wanted varchar(400) not null,
primary key(ad_id),
foreign key(advertiser) references Users(username)
);

create table Ad_Target_Categories
(
ad_id varchar(400) not null,
category varchar(400) not null,
primary key(ad_id,category),
foreign key(ad_id) references Advertisements(ad_id)
);

create table Views
(
user varchar(400) not null,
video varchar(400) not null,
viewed_at varchar(400) not null,
rating varchar(400) not null,
ad_shown varchar(400) not null,
ad_clicked varchar(400) not null,
primary key(user,video,viewed_at),
foreign key(user) references Users(username),
foreign key(video) references Videos(video_id)
);

create table Partners
(
username varchar(400) not null,
revenue_share varchar(400) not null,
primary key(username),
foreign key(username) references Users(username)
);
```

0)List the advertisement ID, and advertiser name and email for each advertisement with a CPM (cost per mille, the price paid per one thousand views wanted) of less than 7 cents.

Is this query correct : ?

```
select *from ad_id,advertiser,email
from advertisements,users
where price <0.07;
```

I wanted help in writing the following SQL queries considering the above database

1)Find the total price of all advertisements targeted at each category. (An advertisement targeted at multiple categories is counted in every category that it is targeted at.)

2)List the names of all advertisers who have had at least one of their advertisements shown more times than they had requested. Each advertiser should not be listed more than once.

3)Find the three partners who earned the most in the month of June 2012. List their names and June 2012 earnings. Partners are paid based on their revenue share and on a per ad shown basis.

4)Find all videos that have received no views since the first two weeks after they were uploaded. For each such video, give the name of the upload user who uploaded it, the video title, and the date and time it was uploaded.

5)List the names of all users in order of date registered with the newest member first. For those users who have uploaded at least one video, also give the number of views on their most-viewed video.

6)Find the five videos with the lowest average rating despite having been rated by their own uploader with the highest rating of 5. List their video ID, title and average rating.

Comment: simply stating your requirements does not constitute a real question on SO. WHy should anyone do your work for you? (and for free?)

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing this collaborative web site with DoMyWork.com or ICantBeBothered.net  Please read this site's FAQs ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq ) to better understand the type of question which are a good fit for this forum.

Comment: You registered those didn't you :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question "Is this query correct", I note that the query won't run at all since there's an extra FROM stuck in the middle.

Once you get it running, the technique for determining whether it's correct would be to insert into the table a set of rows (say, 10 or 20) that contain every edge case you can think of (more than the amount, less than the amount, exactly equal to the amount) so that you know, in advance, what the correct set of returned rows would be.  Then, run your query and compare to the expected output.

I'll also suggest that you give some more thought to your column data types rather than making them all VARCHAR.  You'll see that there are several types more appropriate for storing money amounts.  Using VARCHAR, you may get some comparison anomalies that produce the wrong results.